# Multiple users executing the same workflow

Tags: snakemake

Are there guidelines regarding how to share a Snakemake workflow among multiple users on the same data under Linux, or is the whole thing considered bad practice?

Let me explain in case it's not clear:

Suppose user A executes a workflow in directory `dir/`. Assume the workflow terminates successfully, and he/she then properly sets file/directory permissions recursively on all output and intermediate files and the `.snakemake/` subdirectory for other users to read/write, of course.

User B subsequently navigates to `dir/`, adds input files to the workflow, then executes it. Can anything go wrong?

TL;DR: I'm asking about non-concurrent execution of the same workflow by distinct users on the same system, and on the same data on disk. Is Snakemake designed for such use cases?

Comment: Is the core goal to share the intermediate files to avoid re-compute?

Comment: the goal is to share all files in order to avoid both re-compute *and* data duplication

Comment: apologies SultanOrazbayev and @dariober, I realize now that my question was ambiguous. I've reformulated it above

Comment: From the perspective of Snakemake, it doesn't matter at all who executes a workflow, as long as file/directory permissions are set properly. So Snakemake isn't designed for it, but there's nothing stopping you from using it like that. What would?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run `snakemake --nolock`  which will prevent locking of the directory, so multiple runs can be made from inside the same directory. However, without lock, there's now an opening for errors due to concurrent runs trying to modify the same files. It's probably OK, if you are certain that this will be avoided, e.g. if you are in constant communication with another user about which files will be modified.

An alternative option is to create a third directory/path, and put all the data there. This way you can work from separate directories/path and avoid costly recomputes.

Comment: thank you Sultan! However Snakemake lock files disappear once the workflow finishes, so I fail to see how that answers my question... Regarding the alternative option, I may be missing something but in my case that would imply duplicating terabytes of data, so it's not a viable solution

Comment: Ah, OK, I thought you wanted to allow concurrent running two non-overlapping workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that from the point of view of snakemake, and workflow management in  general, it's ok for user B to add or update input files and re-run the pipeline. After all, one of the advantages of a workflow management system is to update results according to new input. The problem is that user A could find her results updated without being aware of it.

From the top of my head and without more detail this is what I would suggest. Make snakemake read the list of input files from a table (pandas comes in handy for this) or from some configuration file. Keep this sample sheet under version control (with git/github) together with the Snakefile and other source code.

When users update the working directory with new files, they will also need to update the sample sheet in order for snakemake to "see" the new input and other users will know about it via version control. I prefer this setup over dumping files in a directory and letting snakemake process whatever is in there.

Comment: thank you dariober! I forgot to mention that I assumed perfect coordination among the users. Non-concurrent execution of the same workflow on the same system, and on the same data on disk. Is Snakemake designed for such use cases?

Comment: @JulienLag From comments you posted it seems the scope of your question has changed from how to handle multiple users to avoiding data and processing duplication. Anyway, I would say the answer is yes, snakemake does not recreate a file unless its input files have a newer timestamp (i.e. the file has become obsolete).